# Class attribute in <td> disappears in browser?

Tags: php, html, css

Good evening, I have this table with buttons in it. And to recognize values in the tables, I would like to add classes to a table data cell (). However, when I do this, the class disappears when opened in the browser. Why is this? I'd like to add the class `'username'` to `<td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>`

Part of my code:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($fetch_query_run) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_query_run)) {
            ?> 
            <tr>
                <td><strong class="user_id"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['position']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['merits']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['overallflights']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['timezone']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-datatable btn-icon btn-transparent-dark me-2 edit_data"><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-datatable btn-icon btn-transparent-dark delete_data"><i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            
            
            <?php
        }
} else {
    ?>
        <tr colspan="7">No Record Found</tr>
    <?php
}
```

I tried doing `<td class="username"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>`
I fixed it within  at $row['id] but as I don't have  on the line of username, that is not an option. In the browser it just disappears.

[image: Attribute disappearing]

I tried searching online for different attributes or fixes, but no one seems to experience my problems.

Comment: there is no logical reason why attributes added to your PHP code should disappear when rendered in the browser. Certainly nothing in what you have shown above code yields that behaviour so have you confirmed the same issue with a statically generated php test page?

Comment: The posted code block does not show setting an attribute on a `<td>` element, only some additional notes. Please update it with your actual code that you are trying.

Comment: Not related to your problem, and I'm not saying I necessarily recommend this, but if you are targeting something with CSS, the `:has()` selector allows you to "peek inside" a DOM element to write some additional rules about that element: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/dyrVzmY. Obviously you'd want to fix your problem, so this is just a "good-to-know"

Comment: I can't see that a class is being added. Do you mean setting a class (which is an attribute) in the td or are you just trying to put the username into the content of the cell? Are you certain there is a username?

Comment: What is the output of `$row['username']`? The class shouldn't get added to the DOM if there are [invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selector)